# when we enter the username in login page, Home page should display Welcome {username} , how to show this using react js

Tags: reactjs, authentication

when we enter the username in the login page, the Home page should display Welcome {username}, how to show this using react js

Comment: Show us what you have done.

Comment: https://github.com/NishanShamika/react-loginpage

Comment: I want to do this without a backend

Comment: simply I type the whatever user name and I press the login button then I want to show the i entered user name in home page

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can set state in `react-router`:

```
<button type="submit" onClick={() => navigate("/Home", { state: your_data })}>
 Log In
</button>
```

And you can access it in target page using `useLocation` hook:

```
let location = useLocation();
console.log(location.state);
```

Comment: thank you it's work